# Can brownian motion have two indices?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is there such a thing as Brownian motion with two indices? In particular, does something like this exist: $$W_t(s)= \epsilon_t \sqrt{s}\,,$$

where, for fixed $t$, the usual properties hold:

- $W_t(0)=0$.
- $s \to W_t(s)$ is continuous in $s$.
- $\{W_t(s)\}_{s\geq0}$ has independent stationary increments in $s$
- for any $s$, $W_t(s)$ is $N(0,1)$,

but where, additionally, for fixed $s$, $W_t(s)$ is a discrete-time normal random variable, following, say, an AR(1) process with respect to $t$?

The $s$-index would be spatial, for instance, and the $t$-index temporal.

How would one handle conditional expectations $\mathrm{E}_t[\cdot]$, $\mathrm{E}_s[\cdot]$,
$\mathrm{E}_{s,t}[\cdot]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in multivariate Brownian motion. That is, a Brownian motion that takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$. You can then take $t=1,...,d$. If you choose an appropriate covariance matrix, this should result in a sample of length $d$ of an AR process, at each time point.

There are also generalizations to infinite dimensions.

Comment: I see, that’s a nice suggestion, thank you! And the AR coefficient, call it $\rho$, would then be determined by the covariance matrix that one assumes?

Comment: It's the other way around: the AR coefficient determines the covariance matrix. Not all covariance matrices correspond to a Gaussian AR process, but each Gaussian AR process does correspond to a multivariate normal distribution with some covariance matrix.

Comment: Note that the covariance matrix for a particular AR process is unique if you assume stationarity (and otherwise it is not, because you can choose an arbitrary initialisation)